# How to do more cleaner code than adding class active and hidden to every element

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Full code:** https://codepen.io/vvaciej/pen/abPdEBN

Program rely on 8 food areas and there is 3 buttons that segregate them: breakfast, lunch and button all.

I did it by adding class active and hidden to every element

like there:

```js
allButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    firstFoodElement.classList.add('active');
    firstFoodElement.classList.remove('hidden');

    secondFoodElement.classList.add('active');
    secondFoodElement.classList.remove('hidden');

    thirdFoodElement.classList.add('active');
    thirdFoodElement.classList.remove('hidden');

    fourthFoodElement.classList.add('active');
    fourthFoodElement.classList.remove('hidden');

    fifthFoodElement.classList.add('active');
    fifthFoodElement.classList.remove('hidden');

    sixthFoodElement.classList.add('active');
    sixthFoodElement.classList.remove('hidden');

    seventhFoodElement.classList.add('active');
    seventhFoodElement.classList.remove('hidden');

    eightthFoodElement.classList.add('active');
    eightthFoodElement.classList.remove('hidden');
});
```

Code works like it should, but I know I would be punished as junior programmer so I want to do the same but more cleaner
Counting on your help

Comment: Please show the HTML structure. The neatest solution may depend on what that is.

Comment: Create a small example with your related HTML and CSS so we can best assist you here - there might be some great options that can be leveraged here.

Comment: My sincerest apologies @MaciekS, my eyes complete glazed over your codepen link in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77590493/633183). My comment is completely ignorant in that context :'(

Comment: Note: the codepen in this question no longer contains the code you asked about, it was reused (same URL) for your new question. This is precisely why it is important to copy the complete code reference for the question, as off-site resources can become stale or unavailable.

Comment: Please put the HTML and any other relevant code directly into your question as I requested initially. As @Mulan has discovered, the question is now virtually useless as the code has been overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend rewriting the code to categorize 'food', 'breakfast', 'lunch', and 'drink' as classes. So, instead of using `<div class="first-food-display active">`, you could use something like `<div class="food-display lunch-display active">`. This implies that this element would be displayed only when either the "all" or "lunch" buttons are selected.

Following that, I'd suggest modifying the JavaScript in the following manner. I tested it on your codepen and it works.

```
const foodElements = document.querySelectorAll('.food-display');
const breakfastElements = document.querySelectorAll('.breakfast-display');
const lunchElements = document.querySelectorAll('.lunch-display');
const drinkElements = document.querySelectorAll('.drink-display');

const displayElements = (elements) => {
  elements.forEach(element => {
    element.classList.add('active');
    element.classList.remove('hidden');
  });
}

const hideElements = (elements) => {
  elements.forEach(element => {
    element.classList.add('hidden');
    element.classList.remove('active');
  });
}

allButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  displayElements(foodElements);
});

breakfastButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  hideElements(foodElements);
  displayElements(breakfastElements);
});

lunchButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  hideElements(foodElements);
  displayElements(lunchElements);
});

drinksButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  hideElements(foodElements);
  displayElements(drinkElements);
});
```

Comment: This is not universal, because when adding a new type of food, you have to go into the code and add it as a new button.

Answer (score 2):

Add some parameters to the buttons and to the `div` that will be filtered. For example `data-filter`. And then use them.
I would do something like this (this is just an example and I'm sure you can improve it):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.filter-buttons button').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.filter-buttons button').forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
    this.classList.add('active');
    const { filter } = button.dataset;
    if (filter === 'all') {
      document.querySelectorAll('.filter>div').forEach(el => el.classList.add('active'));
      return;
    }
    document.querySelectorAll('.filter>div').forEach(el => {
      const filterProps = el.dataset.filter.split(',');
      el.classList.toggle('active', filterProps.includes(filter));
    });
  })
})
```

```css
.filter-buttons {
  display: flex;
}
.filter-buttons button.active {
  border-color: red;
}

.filter>div:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-buttons">
  <button class="active" data-filter="all">all</button>
  <button data-filter="breakfast">breakfast</button>
  <button data-filter="lunch">lunch</button>
  <button data-filter="drinks">drinks</button>
</div>
<div class="filter">
  <div class="active" data-filter="breakfast">breakfast</div>
  <div class="active" data-filter="breakfast">breakfast</div>
  <div class="active" data-filter="drinks">drinks</div>
  <div class="active" data-filter="lunch">lunch</div>
  <div class="active" data-filter="drinks">drinks</div>
  <div class="active" data-filter="breakfast,lunch">breakfast, lunch</div>
</div>
```

P.S. The example also takes into account the situation when it can be both breakfast and lunch

Answer (score 0):

Like you I found your initial code set to be quite busy but more importantly a lot to maintain (Not DRY).

Now my answer is a bit more than needed to illustrate how some things might be done - even with less code overall.

Here I used some data attributes to contain information about the target elements by "type" including a target selector the worked with that.

- Note the `showHideAll(true, tgs.target);` where I pass the target and a true/false to show and hide - hide them all initially on a button click then show the ones we want.
  Note how for each element this calls `showMe(el, showMe)` where I simply set the value with the "showMe" value i.e. `el.dataset.showme = showMe;`
- Using the dataset then I only need set or clear (value "") the data attribute - then I don't have to toggle/add/remove two classes for each element and then simply target that with CSS to hide the element: `.food-container[data-showme="false"] { display: none; }` - the other CSS with this data attribute is just to 'show' it but it might even be removed - I left it for clarity.
- I used "all" value in the data attribute (I parse to JSON) `data-targets='{"scope":"all","target":".food-container"}'` scope just to show that it might also but "one" or "single" etc. - see where I use that "all" scope value in code.
- Attached using a collection of `const menuButtons =` except I also excluded the "All" button `:not(.all-button)` to create a "custom" event handler for the button color just to illustrate how to call the original event handler from that after I did the custom color - just to show how.
- Use a bit more generic named classes to clarify intent like `.food-content .content-description` notice I removed all the `first`, `second` everywhere except on the images - since those differ by that class - only for CSS and not for functionality.
- I change the ``` ul``li ``` to be div and spans etc. since I find it not styled as a list anyway so why add the burden of removing the list styles to the CSS.
- Some for the `p` since it was being styled differently than the default anyway and a div is more appropriate perhaps.
- I found the whole CSS selector prefix `html body main` to be quite busy - it is all going to be in there anyway so I removed it.
- Removed all the "position" related CSS like `position: absolute;` and just let the grid and flex control the flow and be a bit more responsive
- Removed the "author" as not part of the question - and not often seen in real pages to simplify this demo
- Added some ugly borders just to show what is where for my brain
- changed the `px` to use a modern `em` - could be `rem` also but either way it is simpler to calculate things IMHO - not part of the question though.
- I added a "Cola" button simply to illustrate how adding it is ONLY in the HTML and no code change to handle it with the rest of the buttons - so you could add "Side Items" like chips, fries or salad etc. and only need the HTML added with the data attributes.
- I used `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 13em);` to flow the menu items but you might use minmax or some other than the `13em` width; this can also be done with the buttons but I left them in a row.
- NOT part of the question but I used `display: grid; place-items: center;` to "super center" a set of elements in its container a couple places.

Some may not like the class vs data attribute to toggle visibility but both are CSS targetable and I find setting one rather than toggling two easier.  You could even handle multi-state such as a red-yellow-green stoplight concept or a "highlight on the menu today" or NOT by just using the value and some CSS additions - like color it green etc.

```js
const headerArea = document.querySelector('.header-area');

function changeHeaderBackgroundWhenScroll() {
  const windowScrolling = window.scrollY;
  if (windowScrolling < 9999 && windowScrolling > 20) {
    headerArea.style = 'background-color: #1f1f1ff9; transition: .1s;';
  } else {
    headerArea.style = 'background-color: transparent; transition: .1s;';
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', changeHeaderBackgroundWhenScroll);

const menuButtons = headerArea
  .querySelectorAll('.header-button:not(.all-button)');

const allButton = headerArea
  .querySelector('.all-button');

function showMe(el, showMe) {
  el.dataset.showme = showMe;
}

function showHideAll(showAll, selector) {
  const allFoods = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  allFoods.forEach(function(el) {
    showMe(el, showAll);
  });
}

function buttonEventHandler(event) {
  const ptgs = JSON.parse(this.closest('.header-buttons').dataset.targets);
  const orgB = this.closest('.header-buttons').querySelector('.header-button[data-picked="orange"]');
  if (orgB && !(orgB === this)) {
    orgB.dataset.picked = "";
  }
  showHideAll(false, ptgs.target);
  const tgs = JSON.parse(this.dataset.targets);
  if (tgs.scope = "all") {
    showHideAll(true, tgs.target);
  }
}

allButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.dataset.picked = "orange";
  buttonEventHandler.call(this);
});
menuButtons.forEach((menuItem) => {
  menuItem.addEventListener('click', buttonEventHandler);
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  height: -moz-max-content;
  height: max-content;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
}

body {
  height: -moz-max-content;
  height: max-content;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

body main {
  /*  height: 100%;*/
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "main";
}

body main .header {
  grid-area: header;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 8em;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: solid 1px #00ff00;
}

body main .main-content {
  grid-area: main;
  border: solid 2px #ff00ff;
}

.header-area .header-title {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #ececec;
  color: #ececec;
}

.header-area .header-buttons {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 5em;
  border: solid yellow 1px;
}

.header-area .header-buttons .buttons-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  place-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
}

.header-area .header-buttons .buttons-container .header-button {
  padding: 0.625em 1.25em 0.625em 1.25em;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid rgba(213, 213, 213, 0.3333333333);
  color: #d5d5d5;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.header-area .header-buttons .buttons-container .header-button[data-picked="orange"] {
  color: orange;
}

.header-area .header-buttons .buttons-container .header-button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(213, 213, 213, 0.1254901961);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

 .main-content {
  grid-area: main;
  height: -moz-max-content;
  height: max-content;
  width: 100%;
}

.food-content .content-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.625em;
  padding-bottom: 0.1875em;
  color: #d5d5d5;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid #9e9e9e60;
}

.food-content .content-item .price {
  color: #fab0a0;
}

.food-content .content-description {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  height: -moz-max-content;
  height: max-content;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  font-weight: 500;
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  color: rgba(213, 213, 213, 0.7450980392);
}

.food-control {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  -moz-column-gap: 1.25em;
  column-gap: 1.25em;
}

.main-content .main-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 13em);
  gap: 1em;
}

.main-content .main-grid .food-container {
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.9;
  border: 0.1875em solid rgba(250, 176, 160, 0.768627451);
  border-radius: 1.25em;
}

.first-food-image {
  background: url(/Images/jajecznica.jpg);
}

.main-content .main-grid .second-food-display .second-food .second-food-image {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 100%, transparent), url(/Images/burrito.jpg);
}

.main-content .main-grid .third-food-display .third-food .third-food-image {
  background: url(/Images/nalesniki.jpg);
}

.main-content .main-grid .fourth-food-display .fourth-food .fourth-food-image {
  background: url(/Images/pierogi.jpg);
}

.main-content .main-grid .fifth-food-display .fifth-food .fifth-food-image {
  background: url(/Images/pomidorowa.jpg);
}

.main-content .main-grid .sixth-food-display .sixth-food .sixth-food-image {
  background: url(/Images/rosol-domowy.jpeg);
}

.main-content .main-grid .seventh-food-display .seventh-food .seventh-food-image {
  background: url(/Images/cola.webp);
}

.main-content .main-grid .eightth-food-display .eightth-food .eightth-food-image {
  background-image: url(/Images/piwo.jpg);
}

.food-container[data-showme],
.food-container[data-showme="true"] {
  display: block;
}

.food-container[data-showme="false"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b367f4fd12.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;500;600;700;800&family=Open+Sans:wght@400;500;600;700;800&family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700;800&family=Quicksand:wght@400;500;600;700;800&family=Roboto:wght@400;500;600;700;800&family=Rubik:wght@400;500;600;700;800&display=swap">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">

<main>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-area">
      <span class="header-title">Todays Menu <span class="project-text-header">Project</span></span>
      <div class="header-buttons" data-targets='{"scope":"all","target":".food-container"}'>
        <span class="buttons-container">
          <span class="header-button all-button" data-targets='{"scope":"all","target":".food-container"}'>All</span>
        <span class="header-button breakfast-button" data-targets='{"scope":"all","target":".food-container[data-foodtype=breakfast]"}'>Breakfast</span>
        <span class="header-button lunch-button" data-targets='{"scope":"all","target":".food-container[data-foodtype=lunch]"}'>Lunch</span>
        <span class="header-button drinks-button" data-targets='{"scope":"all","target":".food-container[data-general=drinks]"}'>Drinks</span>
        <span class="header-button cola-button" data-targets='{"scope":"all","target":".food-container.cola"}'>Cola</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="main-grid">
      <div class="food-container" data-foodtype="breakfast">
        <div class="food-control">
          <div class="first-food-image"></div>
          <div class="food-content" vdata-foodtype="breakfast">
            <span class="content-item">Eggs<span class="price">3.99$</span></span>
            <div class="content-description">
              Jajecznica rozpieści Twoje podniebienie i sprawi, że wrócisz po więcej.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="food-container" data-foodtype="breakfast">
        <div class="second-food  food-control">
          <div class="second-food-image"></div>
          <div class="food-content">
            <span class="content-item">Burrito<span class="price">4.99$</span></span>
            <div class="content-description">
              Nasze burrito to połączenie świeżych składników, i miękkiej tortilli.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="food-container" data-foodtype="breakfast">
        <div class="food-control">
          <div class="third-food-image"></div>
          <div class="food-content">
            <span class="content-item">Crepes<span class="price">7.99$</span></span>
            <div class="content-description">
              Pyszne naleśniki z dodatkami do wyboru.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="food-container" data-foodtype="lunch">
        <div class="food-control">
          <div class="fourth-food-image"></div>
          <div class="food-content">
            <span class="content-item">Dumplings<span class="price">7.99$</span></span>
            <div class="content-description">
              Nasze pierogi to połączenie najlepszych składników i starannie zachowanych receptur.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="food-container" data-foodtype="lunch">
        <div class="food-control">
          <div class="fifth-food-image">
          </div>
          <div class="food-content">
            <span class="content-item">Tomato soup<span class="price">2.99$</span></span>
            <div class="content-description">
              Wyjątkowo kremowa, pełna intensywnego smaku pomidorów i aromatycznych ziół.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="food-container" data-foodtype="lunch">
        <div class="food-control">
          <div class="sixth-food-image"></div>
          <div class="food-content">
            <span class="content-item">Broth<span class="price">2.99$</span></span>
            <div class="content-description">
              Delikatnie gotowany bulion wzbogacony soczystym mięsem i świeżymi warzywami.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="food-container cola" data-foodtype="lunch" data-general="drinks">
        <div class="food-control">
          <div class="seventh-food-image"></div>
          <div class="food-content">
            <span class="content-item">Coca Cola<span class="price">1.99$</span></span>
            <div class="content-description">
              Coca-Cola, to ikona orzeźwienia i doskonały towarzysz każdego posiłku.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="food-container" data-foodtype="lunch" data-general="drinks">
        <div class="food-control">
          <div class="eightth-food-image"></div>
          <div class="food-content">
            <span class="content-item">Beer<span class="price">1.99$</span></span>
            <div class="content-description">
              Pyszniutkie piwo 6% prosto od Harnaś.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```